# semantic web + linked data integration

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, data-integration

i'm new to semantic web.
I'm trying to do a sample application where i can query data from different data sources in one query.
i have created a small rdf file which contains references to dbpedia resources for defining localities. my question is : how can i get the data contained in my file and other information which is in the description of the distant resource (for example : the name of the person from the local file, and the total poulation in a city dbpedia-owl:populationTotal from the distant rdf file).
i don't really understand the sparql query language, i tried to use the JENA ARQ API with the SERVICE keyword but it doesn't solve the problem. 
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like the [Semantic Web Client Library](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/ng4j/semwebclient/), which tries to leverage the GGG. Albeit, the standard exploration algorithm of this framework is that it follows rdfs:seeAlso links. Nevertheless, the general approach seems to be what your are looking for, i.e., you would create a local graph that consists of your seed graph and that traverse the relations up to a certain level, e.g., three steps, resolves the URIs and load that content into your local triple. Utilising advanced technologies like SPARQL federation might be something for later ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have retrived data from two different sources using SPARQL query with named graphs.
I used jena-ARQ to execute the sparql query.